# Child class follow structure of parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following two classes:

```
class AcceptCommand extends Command {
    init(client, db) {
        super.init(client, db);
    }


    async hasPermission() {

    }

    async run() {
        if (this.hasPermission()) {

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
export class Command {
    init(client, db) {
        this.client = client;
        this.db = db;
    }

    setTrigger(trigger) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
    }

    getTrigger() {
        return this.trigger;
    }

    async hasPermission() {

    }

    async run() {
        if (this.hasPermission()) {

        }
    }
}
```

I want that when the run() function is run it first checks if the user has permissions (`this.hasPermission()`).

In the parent class `Command` I do:

```
async hasPermission() {

}

async run() {
    if (this.hasPermission()) {

    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this also apply to all the child classes without having to do the same in every child class the same?

Comment: Notice that you'll want to use `if (await this.hasPermission())` given that `hasPermission` is an `async` method

Answer (score 1):

You can add another method wich will be executed if `hasPermission` returns true. And override this function in child class. Like this:

```js
class Command {
    actionIfHasPermission () {
     console.log('Command actionIfHasPermission')
    }

    async hasPermission() {
        console.log('Command hasPermission')
        return false
    }

    async run() {
        if (this.hasPermission()) {
            this.actionIfHasPermission()
        }
    }
}

class AcceptCommand extends Command {     
    actionIfHasPermission() {
     console.log('AcceptCommand actionIfHasPermission')
    }

    async hasPermission() {
     console.log('AcceptCommand hasPermission')
        return true
    }
}

const instance = new AcceptCommand()

instance.run()
```